# Can the solutions to a homogeneous second order differential equation be a function and its inverse?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse

Is there an equation of the form $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y= 0$, such that the two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are inverses? I did the following work, where I made the assumption that $p(x) = 0$ and $y_1 = Ax^n$,  but arrived to a seemingly incorrect solution that fails upon rechecking: $$y_1 = \frac{1}{n^2}x^n, y_2 = (n^2x)^{\frac1n}, q(x) =(1-n)nx^{2-2n}$$
Here is my work:
[image: Here is my work]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cauchy-Euler's differential equation with solution $y_1=x^2$ and $y_2=\sqrt x$.
$$x^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$$
Then find the constants $b$ and $c$.
Substitute $y=x^m$:
$$\implies m^2+(b-1)m+c=0$$
Then $m=\dfrac 12$ and $m=2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to construct a such equation. Let $y_1=x,y_2=\frac1x$ and $y=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$. Then from
$$ y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y =0 $$
one has
$$ C_1[p(x)+xq(x)]+C_2\frac1{x^3}[2-xp(x)+x^2q(x)]=0. $$
Let
$$ p(x)+xq(x)=0, 2-xp(x)+x^2q(x)=0 $$
which give $p(x)=\frac1x,q(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$. Thus the DE becomes
$$ y''+\frac1x y'-\frac1{x^2} y=0. $$